# NuxtJs - How to fix 'page not found' error in nuxtjs when redirecting programmatically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently working on a project that was made in Vue, but I had to convert it into Nuxt.

I got a navigation guard running in the app (using `router.beforeEach()`).

Now, when I access the base URL `localhost:3000`, it shows me the image below

[image: nuxt js this page could not be found]
and the code below is the block of code that handles that path.

```
if (to.path == '/') {
      switch (auth.getRole()) {
        case '1':
          next({
            path: '/route_1'
          })
          break
        case '2':
          next({
            path: '/route_2'
          })
          break
        default:
          next({
            path: '/route_3'
          })
          break
      }
    }
```

But when I access it directly from the address bar, by typing directly the URL `localhost:3000/login`, it renders the page properly.

**EDIT:**

Here's my pages folder.

[image]

Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: could you show us your pages folder structure

Comment: @Ifaruki updated the question. Added my pages folder.

Comment: was thinking of that u might forgot the `index.vue` file but its here. hmm.. it should render the `index.vue` file by default on `/`

Comment: routing is actually handled by your folder strucutre but i guess u know it already

Comment: did you thy to stop and re-run your server? i had  issue sometimes when i add or remove file into pages folder and re-run it solved the problem

Comment: @AliHosseini yes I did, but unfortunately it's still not working

Comment: While migrating to Nuxt Bridge I faced the issue of routes not working at all. The only route that is working is the base '/' route. Navigate to any other page by any means (router-link, router.push, change url manually) just shows me the "this page could not be found" message, and no errors at all in console...

Answer (score 0):

1- nuxt build

2- nuxt start

First you need to build the project and then you will be able to run project from dist/ folder.